# How to locate the element in Email?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to activate the account from the email.
This is the mail i am using: http://www.yopmail.com/en/
its a temporary mail . I used all the methods as far as my knowledge but its even finding the element and returns the empty list. I want to click the Activate anchor tag. This is the structure:

```html
    <p class="description center" style="font-family:Roboto, 'Arial Narrow', Arial;margin:0;text-align:center;color:#797979;line-height:24px;font-size:16px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:20px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    <a style="color:#f04877;" href="https://mandrillapp.com/track/click/31118617/devauth.eventjini.com?p=eyJzIjoiTFlnX0FQclZFN1d6bTNMUk9uNnFiVGxuX0QwIiwidiI6MSwicCI6IntcInVcIjozMTExODYxNyxcInZcIjoxLFwidXJsXCI6XCJodHRwczpcXFwvXFxcL2RldmF1dGguZXZlbnRqaW5pLmNvbVxcXC9hdXRoXFxcL2FzdVxcXC9QR09TVTcweS0yMDIwMDMwNl8wODQyNDFcIixcImlkXCI6XCJjYmE3OGM0OGY0OTM0MDc3ODZmMGQyYzY4YWE4YjU1ZVwiLFwidXJsX2lkc1wiOltcIjcwYjBiYTU0MGViMGI0ZWUwOTM2OThlYTU4NjQ2NDRlMWEwYmU4OTZcIl19In0" rel="nofollow">
        <b>Activate</b>
    </a>
</p>
<p class="description center" style="font-family:Roboto, 'Arial Narrow', Arial;margin:0;text-align:center;color:#797979;line-height:24px;font-size:16px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:20px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">OR</p>
<p class="description center" style="font-family:Roboto, 'Arial Narrow', Arial;margin:0;text-align:center;color:#797979;line-height:24px;font-size:16px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:20px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    Copy and paste the link below in your browser to activate your Eventjini ID.
</p>
```

Code trials:

```html
 elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/center/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/center/p[4]/a/b")))
 for element in elements:
     print(element.text)
     if element.text == 'Activate':
         element.click()
```

and

```
//b[text()='Activate']
```

Comment: @DebanjanB Please read [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), pay close attention to the first paragraph and the *Should I use tags in titles?* section.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try clicking  using XPATH.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text() = 'Activate']").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.description.center>a[href*='eventjini']>b"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='description center']/a[contains(@href, 'eventjini')]/b[text()='Activate']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```